# pyinstaller is not recognized as an internal or external command error after successful installation

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller, command-prompt

there is a pyinstaller error that occurred whilst I was using it.

I went on cmd (command prompt) and entered: pip install pyinstaller.

it worked, but when I went to the location of my file and used pyinstaller: I typed this in:

```
C:\users\[___]\PycharmProjects\FismaPythonIDE.py pyinstaller --onefile -w FismaPythonIDE.py
```

I hit 'enter' but it said:

```
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

does someone know what this means?? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
pyinstaller FismaPythonIDE.py --onefile -w
```

Open cmd in same directory where *FismaPythonIDE.py* and use this command.